# How exclude Folder inside folder app when build with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This is my project structure :

```
- src
   - app
       - tenantA
       - tenantB
   - assets
   - index.html
```

How I can exclude folder tenantA when run "`ng build`" 
Thanks

Comment: I did see that. But I not working for me

Answer (score 1):

you can try put that folder in either `tsconfig.app.json` under `/src` or `tsconfig.json` under `root`, like

```
"exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "_backup/**/*"
]
```